# csv formatting issue javascript p5

Tags: javascript, csv, formatting

I hope this is the right place to post this but I figured you might be of help here. I'm working on a p5 javascript project where I load a csv file with loadTable() in the preload() function. And I am saving it again later in my setup() with the saveTable() function when a button is pressed. Now comes my problem, the output csv is not in the right format. The function saveTable() exports the following:

`sessionId,timeStamp,selectedItems100000,3-5-2018_10:24,EPC123412341234123412340001`

But i need it to output it as seperate rows instead of all the rows placed besides each other. Like this:

`sessionId,timeStamp,selectedItems
100000,3-5-2018_10:24,EPC123412341234123412340001`

This is the part of the code that prepares and exports the csv file:

```
var newRow = sessionLog.addRow();
newRow.setNum('sessionId', sessionId);
newRow.setString('timeStamp', timeStamp);
newRow.setString('selectedItems', selectedItems);
saveTable(sessionLog, 'sessionLog.csv', 'csv');
```

What am I doing wrong? Could any of you help me with this issue?

Comment: Where are these functions from?

Comment: from the p5 libraries for JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Where does sessionLog come from? Did you register the columns first?

```
sessionLog.addColumn('sessionId')
sessionLog.addColumn('timeStamp')
sessionLog.addColumn('selectedItems')
```

See also this page: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveTable

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wouter! I've spent sooo much time on that reference page that I almost memorised the contents... However, I am having trouble figuring out why I need redefine the columns, if they are already present in my session log csv file. Is my doubt true or do I still need to define the columns?

Comment: I gave it a try, as suspected, the columns are defined a second time and are doubled in the log file

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the headers were already in there, I thought you were creating a new file. What happens if you add multiple rows? Are they all on the same line, or are they inserted properly then? Does your existing sessionLog file end with a newline?

Comment: Yes, the new row is placed right behind the headers without a separator. the individual values of the row are separated by commas (please see the first quote field in my initial post. what do you mean by if my existing sessionLog file ends with a new line?